# UTF-16 string compression implementation

Tags: c, compression, unicode-string, lempel-ziv-76

C language/compression algorithm noob here, apologies in advance.

I am looking into a utf-16 string compression algorithm based on Lempel-Ziv as explained here http://www.unicode.org/notes/tn31/

According to the implementation (https://www.unicode.org/notes/tn31/#Performance), a 1014 byte string should be compressed to about 560 (about 60%).

However I downloaded the sample c (https://www.unicode.org/notes/tn31/utf16_compressor.tar.gz) code and tested compressing a string of 1290 length (I added a print statement to print the input and output lengths) but the output length is 3018 after compression. Is there something I am missing or am I misinterpreting the output length? From the code the output buffer of the compression function is an unsigned char (1 byte) array hence meaning the 3018 is actually 3018 bytes?

Comment: It's possible for the output to be larger than the input if the input is not very compressible.

Comment: Thanks @IanAbbott I tried a string consisting the same character e.g. ttttttttttttttttttttttttt and yes the compressed output was indeed smaller than the input. Thanks for the pointer